# Windows Forms get data from database and display in label

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms, ado.net

[image: Windows Form]

I want to grab data from database and display in labels based on what the user selects in the list view.

I'm going off an example that does this with two list views, but I don't know how to do it when I'm sending data to a label.

This is the list view example I'm using (my label code is below this)

```
private void PopulateRecipeIngredients()
{
    string query = "SELECT a.Name FROM Ingredient a " +
        "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientId " +
        "WHERE b.RecipeId = @RecipeId";
    // @ is a parameter

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {

        // whatever recipe is selected in lstRecipes box, get the id of that and pass into query above
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeId", lstRecipes.SelectedValue);


        // DataTable holds the data return from query
        DataTable ingredientTable = new DataTable();

        // SqlDataAdapter object adapter fills the ingredientTable DataTable object with results from query
        adapter.Fill(ingredientTable);

        // Display value of Name ex. salad
        lstIngredients.DisplayMember = "Name";

        // Id column is how we reference
        lstIngredients.ValueMember = "Id";
        // connect list box on form to data in recipeTable
        lstIngredients.DataSource = ingredientTable;
    }
}
```

MY CODE:

```
  private void PopulateCourseDetails()
   {
      string query = "SELECT * FROM Course_Info WHERE Id = @CourseId";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseId", lstCourses.SelectedValue);

        DataTable courseTable = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(courseTable);

        lblCourseId.Text = "Course_id";
        lblCourseSection.Text = "Course_section";
        lblCourseName.Text = "Course_name";
        lblCourseDay.Text = "Course_day";
        lblCourseStartTime.Text = "Course_start_time";
        lblCourseEndTime.Text = "Course_end_time";
        lblCourseProfessor.Text = "Course_professor";
        lblCourseProfessorEmail.Text = "Course_professor_email";


        lstCourses.ValueMember = "Id";

    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the Id, the query shoud be: string query = "SELECT a.Id, a.Name FROM Ingredient a " +
        "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientId " +
        "WHERE b.RecipeId = @RecipeId";

Comment: Thanks, but the recipe code is an example I was using to writemy code.  The recipe code displays info into a listbox based on what is selected in another list box.  It works.  What I want to do is display info in labels based on what is selected in a list box.  I don't know how to get the info out of the DataTable object and into the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lblCourseId.Text = (string)courseTable.Rows[0]["Course_id"]
```

should work as long as you have one row in the result table

Comment: I get an error "Cannot apply indexing to datatable".  The ingredients code I was using to learn how to do this has an extra line of code that mine doesn't have `        lstIngredients.DataSource = ingredientTable;` I don't know if I need something like that, but the label doesn't have a DataSource method

Comment: You are right, it can not be indexed directly. See update. Label does not have DataSource, because it has only one value, it does not make much sense to bind it to the table.

Comment: Your code works.  I didn't add the method to the form load method so it wasn't showing up.  Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your DataTable has now been properly populated, you now have a table with a number of rows.

First you need to pull out the first row

```
var row = courseTable.Rows.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now you've got a row with a number of columns. You can access each column by either index or column name.

```
lblCourseId.Text = row[0];
```

If you want the label to maintain it's header, you can do something like

```
lblCourseId.Text = "Course_id: " + row[0];
```